# Kyvi camera code does not run on Android device

Tags: android, kivy

I am using Kivy and buildozer on OS X (10.10.1), but I cannot get a Kivy camera application to run on my Android device. Kivy applications that do not use camera are fine. Code is below, and I can also post the buildozer spec file and debug information.

```
#================================

import kivy kivy.require('1.4.0')  from kivy.app import App from kivy.uix.widget import Widget from kivy.uix.camera import Camera from kivy.uix.button import Button from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):
    def doscreenshot(self,*largs):
        Window.screenshot(name='screenshot%(counter)04d.jpg')

    def build(self):
        camwidget = Widget()  #Create a camera Widget
        cam = Camera()        #Get the camera
        cam=Camera(resolution=(640,480), size=(500,500))
        cam.play=True         #Start the camera
        camwidget.add_widget(cam)                
        return camwidget
              if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

#==============Buildozer android debug logcat ======

> m# Check configuration tokens m# Ensure build layout m# Check
> configuration tokens m# Preparing build m# Check requirements for
> android m# Search for Git (git) m#  -> found at /opt/local/bin/git m#
> Search for Cython (cython) m#  -> found at /anaconda/bin/cython m#
> Search for Java compiler (javac) m#  -> found at
> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac
> m# Search for Java keytool (keytool) m#  -> found at
> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/keytool
> m# Install platform m# Apache ANT found at
> /Users/vbafna/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4 m# Android
> SDK found at /Users/vbafna/Library/Android/sdk m# Android NDK found at
> /Users/vbafna/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9 m# Check
> application requirements m# Run './distribute.sh -l' m# Cwd
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
> Available modules: android apsw audiostream c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk
> django docutils ffmpeg gevent greenlet hostpython igraph jpeg kivent
> kivy libevent libpq libswift libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto
> msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy openssl paramiko pil plyer png
> polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius
> pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools
> sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift twisted txws wokkel zope m# Application
> requirements already installed, pass m# Check garden requirements m#
> Compile platform m# Run './distribute.sh -l' m# Cwd
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
> Available modules: android apsw audiostream c_igraph cprotobuf cymunk
> django docutils ffmpeg gevent greenlet hostpython igraph jpeg kivent
> kivy libevent libpq libswift libxml2 libxslt libyaml lxml m2crypto
> msgpack mysql_connector netifaces numpy openssl paramiko pil plyer png
> polygon protobuf psutil psycopg2 pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius
> pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python pyyaml sdl setuptools
> sqlalchemy sqlite3 storm swift twisted txws wokkel zope m#
> Distribution already compiled, pass. m# Build the application #34 m#
> Copy application source from /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2
> m# Create directory
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app m#
> Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/imageprocessing.py m#
> Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/log m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/log2 m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/main.py m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/main2py m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0001.jpg
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0002.jpg
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0003.jpg
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0004.jpg
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0005.jpg
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0006.jpg
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/screenshot%(counter)04d0007.jpg
> m# Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/showcase.kv m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/test.kv m# Create directory
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data
> m# Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/background.png
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/faust_github.jpg m#
> Create directory
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/icons
> m# Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/icons/next.png
> m# Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/icons/prev.png
> m# Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/icons/README m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/icons/sourcecode.png m#
> Create directory
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/accordions.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/bubbles.kv m#
> Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/buttons.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/carousel.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/checkboxes.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/codeinput.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/dropdown.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/filechoosers.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/popups.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/progressbar.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/rstdocument.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/scatter.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/screenmanager.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/sliders.kv m#
> Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/spinner.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/splitter.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/switches.kv m#
> Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/tabbedpanel +
> layouts.kv m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/textinputs.kv
> m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/data/screens/togglebutton.kv
> m# Create directory
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/images
> m# Copy /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/images/Green Thumb
> LOGO.png m# Copy
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/images/GreenThumbPic.png m#
> Package the application m# project.properties updated m# Run
> "//anaconda/bin/python build.py --name 'My Demo Application' --version
> 0.1 --package org.test.mycameraapp --private /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app --sdk
> 21 --minsdk 8 --permission INTERNET --orientation landscape debug" m#
> Cwd
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp
> Updated project.properties Updated local.properties
> ---------- build.xml: Failed to find version-tag string. File must be updated. In order to not erase potential customizations, the file will
> not be automatically regenerated. If no changes have been made to the
> file, delete it manually and run the command again. If you have made
> customizations to the build process, the file must be manually
> updated. It is recommended to:    * Copy current file to a safe
> location.     * Delete original file.     * Run command again to generate a
> new file.     * Port customizations to the new file, by looking at the
> new rules file      located at <SDK>/tools/ant/build.xml  * Update file
> to contain
>         version-tag: custom     to prevent file from being rewritten automatically by the SDK tools.
> ---------- Updated file ./proguard-project.txt It seems that there are sub-projects. If you want to update them please use the --subprojects
> parameter. Listing
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/private
> ... Listing
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/private/include
> ... Listing
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/private/include/python2.7
> ... Listing
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/private/lib
> ... Listing
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/private/lib/python2.7
> ...
> 
> -set-mode-check:
> 
> -set-debug-files:
> 
> -check-env:  [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2  [checkenv] Installed at /Users/vbafna/Library/Android/sdk
> 
> -setup:
>      [echo] Project Name: MyDemoApplication-0.1   [gettype] Project Type: Application
> 
> -set-debug-mode:
> 
> -debug-obfuscation-check:
> 
> -pre-build:
> 
> -build-setup: [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 21.1.2
>      [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyDemoApplication-0.1... [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 5.0.1 [gettarget] API level:    
> 21
>      [echo] ----------
>      [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>      [echo] ----------
>      [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyDemoApplication-0.1... [dependency] Library dependencies: [dependency] No Libraries
> [dependency]  [dependency] ------------------
>      [echo] ----------
>      [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...    [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
> 
> -code-gen: [mergemanifest] Found modified input file [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one. [mergemanifest] Manifest
> merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
>      [echo] Handling aidl files...
>      [aidl] Found 1 AIDL files.
>      [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
>      [echo] ----------
>      [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
>      [echo] ----------
>      [echo] Handling Resources...
>      [aapt] Found modified input file
>      [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
>      [echo] ----------
>      [echo] Handling BuildConfig class... [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.
> 
> -pre-compile:
> 
> -compile:
>     [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/classes
>     [javac] Note: /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/src/org/renpy/android/Audio.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>     [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> 
> -post-compile:
> 
> -obfuscate:
> 
> -dex:
>       [dex] input: /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/classes
>       [dex] Found modified input file
>       [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/classes.dex...
> 
> -crunch:    [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/res
> [crunch] To destination dir:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/res
> [crunch] Processing image to cache:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/res/drawable/icon.png
> => /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/res/drawable/icon.png
> [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/res/drawable/icon.png:
> 49% size of source)    [crunch] Crunched 1 PNG files to update cache  
> [crunch]
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/res/drawable/icon.png:
> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been
> edited
> 
> -package-resources:
>      [aapt] Found modified input file
>      [aapt] Creating full resource package...
> 
> -package: [apkbuilder] Found modified input file [apkbuilder] Creating MyDemoApplication-0.1-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug
> key...
> 
> -post-package:
> 
> -do-debug:  [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
>      [echo] Debug Package: /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/MyDemoApplication-0.1-debug.apk
> [propertyfile] Updating property file:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/build.prop
> [propertyfile] Updating property file:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/build.prop
> [propertyfile] Updating property file:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/build.prop
> [propertyfile] Updating property file:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myCameraApp/bin/build.prop
> 
> -post-build:
> 
> debug:
> 
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 4 seconds
> s/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/dropdown.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/filechoosers.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/popups.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/progressbar.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/rstdocument.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/scatter.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/screenmanager.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/sliders.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/spinner.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/splitter.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/switches.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/tabbedpanel
> + layouts.kv assets/private.mp3: /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/textinputs.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/data/screens/togglebutton.kv
> assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/images/Green
> Thumb LOGO.png assets/private.mp3:
> /Users/vbafna/projects/kivyProjects/test2/.buildozer/android/app/images/GreenThumbPic.png
> m# Android packaging done! m# APK MyDemoApplication-0.1-debug.apk
> available in the bin directory m# Search for Git (git) m#  -> found at
> /opt/local/bin/git m# Search for Cython (cython) m#  -> found at
> /anaconda/bin/cython m# Search for Java compiler (javac) m#  -> found
> at
> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/javac
> m# Search for Java keytool (keytool) m#  -> found at
> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/keytool
> m# Run '/Users/vbafna/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices'
> m# Cwd None List of devices attached
```

Comment: you can see this Click Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910065/accessing-android-camera-through-kivy) to fix your problem

Answer (score 3):

The `Camera` widget doesn't work on Android, only on desktop. You can access the [Android Camera via plyer](https://plyer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#plyer.facades.Camera) to take pictures, or use a [custom solution to display a camera preview](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/hiyAJqjhFjo).