# Camera4Kivy capture video

Tags: python, android, camera, kivy, capture

I was trying to capture a video in kivy/android using camera4kivy. but it seems that this function won't work. I tried capture video with location, subdir and filename (kwarg**) but still nothing happend.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from camera4kivy.preview import Preview

class CamApp(App):

    def build(self):

        self.cam = Preview()

        self.cam.connect_camera(enable_analyze_pixels=True)
        self.cam.select_camera('1')

        box1 = BoxLayout()
        box1.add_widget(self.cam)

        try:
            self.cam.capture_video(location = 'shared', subdir='myapp', name='myvid')
        except Exception as e: print(e)

        return box1
 
    def on_stop(self):
        self.cam.disconnect_camera()
        return super().on_stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CamApp().run()
```

> 07-21 16:17:14.405 28320 29758 I python  : JVM exception occurred:
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.startRecording(androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture$OutputFileOptions,
> java.util.concurrent.Executor,
> androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture$OnVideoSavedCallback)' on a null
> object reference java.lang.NullPointerException 07-21 16:17:14.406
> 28320 28320 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last): 07-21
> 16:17:14.406 28320 28320 I python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/android/runnable.py",
> line 38, in run 07-21 16:17:14.407 28320 28320 I python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/camera4kivy/preview_camerax.py",
> line 289, in do_select_camera 07-21 16:17:14.407 28320 28320 I python
> :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 857, in
> jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.**call** 07-21 16:17:14.407 28320 28320 I
> python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 954, in
> jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_method 07-21 16:17:14.407 28320 28320 I
> python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in
> jnius.jnius.check_exception 07-21 16:17:14.407 28320 28320 I python  :
> jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'void
> androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider.unbindAll()' on a null
> object reference java.lang.NullPointerException 07-21 16:17:14.408
> 28320 29758 I python  : [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown 
> provider 07-21 16:17:14.408 28320 29758 I python  : [INFO   ] [Base
> ] Start application main loop 07-21 16:17:14.411 28320 29758 I python
> : [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress... 07-21
> 16:17:14.412 28320 29758 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call
> last): 07-21 16:17:14.412 28320 29758 I python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 31, in 
> 07-21 16:17:14.412 28320 29758 I python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/kivy/app.py",
> line 955, in run 07-21 16:17:14.412 28320 29758 I python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py",
> line 574, in runTouchApp 07-21 16:17:14.413 28320 29758 I python  :
> File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py",
> line 339, in mainloop 07-21 16:17:14.413 28320 29758 I python  :
> File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/kivy/base.py",
> line 391, in idle 07-21 16:17:14.413 28320 29758 I python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/kivy/clock.py",
> line 783, in tick_draw 07-21 16:17:14.414 28320 29758 I python  :
> File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 662, in
> kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame 07-21
> 16:17:14.414 28320 29758 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line
> 708, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame 07-21
> 16:17:14.414 28320 29758 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line
> 704, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events_before_frame 07-21
> 16:17:14.414 28320 29758 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line
> 218, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick 07-21 16:17:14.414 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/kivy/uix/anchorlayout.py",
> line 122, in do_layout 07-21 16:17:14.415 28320 29758 I python  :
> File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 520, in
> kivy.properties.Property.**set** 07-21 16:17:14.415 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1478, in
> kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty.set 07-21 16:17:14.415 28320
> 29758 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 606, in
> kivy.properties.Property._dispatch 07-21 16:17:14.415 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in
> kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch 07-21 16:17:14.416 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1213, in
> kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch 07-21 16:17:14.416 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/camera4kivy/preview_camerax.py",
> line 159, in on_size 07-21 16:17:14.416 28320 29758 I python  :
> File
> "/home/testapp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a/build/python-installs/test/arm64-v8a/camera4kivy/preview_camerax.py",
> line 217, in stop_capture_video 07-21 16:17:14.416 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 857, in
> jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.**call** 07-21 16:17:14.417 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 954, in
> jnius.jnius.JavaMethod.call_method 07-21 16:17:14.417 28320 29758 I
> python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in
> jnius.jnius.check_exception 07-21 16:17:14.417 28320 29758 I python  :
> jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'void
> androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture.stopRecording()' on a null object
> reference java.lang.NullPointerException 07-21 16:17:14.417 28320
> 29758 I python  : Python for android ended. 07-21 16:17:14.540 28320
> 29758 F com.moria.test: mutex.cc:340] destroying mutex with owner or
> contenders. Owner:29737 07-21 16:17:14.541 28320 29737 F
> com.moria.test: debugger_interface.cc:356] Check failed: removed_it ==
> removed_entries.end()

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: is this all your code? What do you expect for this code? GUIs usually need more code - they have to  run `event loop` which runs all functions in GUIs. If you have more code then better show minimal working code with this problem. Maybe problem is in different place.

Comment: @furas I want to learn and this is my test code, all of my code. and i wasn't able to edit my question with traceback but i have managed it like this.

Comment: error message shows in few places `on a null object reference` which may suggest that it couldn't detect/access camera. Do you run it on real phone with Android or on emulator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910065/accessing-android-camera-through-kivy

Comment: @furas real phone

Comment: @Juggernaut it's about taking picture but i want to record video, taking picture with this module is perfect but cant capture video

Answer (score 0):

Kivy does not support encoding video and saving it into a file. It only supports playing video from camera widget.

Comment: Your answer has got nothing to do with the question @Juggernaut

Comment: @unlockme it is answering the question :D

Comment: What you say is right, kivy only supports playing video. But Camera for Kivy does support recording video on android.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation/README](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Camera4Kivy) of Camera4Kivy says, the `preview.connect_camera` method can only be called after `on_start`.

You are calling the connect_camera during the build.

You might want to look at the example of using [camera4kivy here](https://github.com/Android-for-Python/c4k_photo_example/) for more information on how to use it.